# Is pandas read_csv really slow compared to python open?

Tags: python, windows, python-3.x, pandas, python-3.5

my requirement is to remove duplicate rows from csv file, but the size of the file is 11.3GB. So I bench marked the pandas and python file generator.

**Python File Generator:**

```
def fileTestInPy():
    with open(r'D:\my-file.csv') as fp, open(r'D:\mining.csv', 'w') as mg:
        dups = set()
        for i, line in enumerate(fp):
            if i == 0:
                continue
            cols = line.split(',')
            if cols[0] in dups:
                continue
            dups.add(cols[0])
            mg.write(line)
            mg.write('\n')
```

[image: Python File Generator]

**Using Pandas read_csv:**

```
import pandas as pd
df = pd.read_csv(r'D:\my-file.csv', sep=',', iterator=True, chunksize=1024*128)
def fileInPandas():
    for d in df:
        d_clean = d.drop_duplicates('NPI')
        d_clean.to_csv(r'D:\mining1.csv', mode='a')
```

[image: Pandas read_csv]

**Details:**
Size: 11.3 GB
rows: 100 million, but in this 50 million are duplicate
Python Version: 3.5.2
Pandas Version: 0.19.0
RAM: 8GB
CPU: Core-i5 2.60GHz

What I'm observed here, 643 sec took when I use the python file generator, but 1756 took when I use the pandas.

Even my system was not hanged when I used the python file generator, but when I used the pandas my system was hanged.

Am I using correct way in pandas ?
Even I want to do sorting on 11.3GB file, how to do that ?

Comment: Please post code fragments directly, not as screen shots. They are easier to read and are easier to cut/paste.

Comment: @tdelaney sorry for that, now added.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Pandas is not a good choice for this task. It reads the entire 11.3G file into memory and does string-to-int conversions on all of the columns. I'm not surprised that your machine bogged down!

The line-by-line version is much leaner. It doesn't do any conversions, doesn't bother looking at unimportant columns and doesn't keep a large dataset in memory. It is the better tool for the job.

```
def fileTestInPy():
    with open(r'D:\my-file.csv') as fp, open(r'D:\mining.csv', 'w') as mg:
        dups = set()
        next(fp) # <-- advance fp so you don't need to check each line
                 # or use enumerate
        for line in fp:
            col = line.split(',', 1)[0]  # <-- only split what you need
            if col in dups:
                continue
            dups.add(col)
            mg.write(line)
            # mg.write('\n')  # <-- line still has its \n, did you
                              # want another?
```

Also, if this is python 3.x and you know your file is ascii or UTF-8, you could open both files in binary mode and save a conversion.

Comment: Can you please explain how to do sorting on this file ?

Comment: Sort the output file?

Comment: Even after removed duplicate rows, the output file has 6GB. Any better way to do sorting in python ?

Comment: I can't think of anything in python that would beat the GNU `sort` command. So, in python, `subprocess.check_call(['sort', '--parallel=6', r'D:\mining.csv'])`.

Comment: is sort is available in windows ?

Comment: ...another option is to start putting this in a database like `sqlite` and indexing it there.

Comment: [gnuwin32](http://gnuwin32.sourceforge.net/packages/coreutils.htm) has it.